# Puppeteer's page.evaluate does not consider i in for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I've been trying to iterate over a list of divs, nearly identical besides the data displayed in them, that are under a certain section of the dom, `<aside>`, in order to grab the innerText from each one of them. The result functions properly when hardcoding an `nth-child` number, however, trying to iterate it in a for loop produces the error: `Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: i is not defined at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:1:130`. Confused as to what's going on here.

```
    for (let i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
        let info = await page.evaluate(
            () => [...document.querySelectorAll(`#root > main > div.sc-jcVebW.eVwwrC > div.sc-bZSQDF.dgraCx > div > aside > div:nth-child(${i}) > div.sc-dlfnbm.ujoHC > div.sc-hKgILt.beOqPu > div > h2`)].map(elem => elem.innerText)
        );
        console.log(info)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions passed to `page.evaluate` get stringified so they can be run in the browser, so they don't have lexical scope inheritance that one would normally expect. You need to pass another argument to `page.evaluate` to indicate the parameters the function should take.

I'd also recommend making the code more readable: put the long selector on its own line, and use `const` instead of `let` (if at all possible):

```
const info = await page.evaluate(
    (i) => {
        const selector = `#root > main > div.sc-jcVebW.eVwwrC > div.sc-bZSQDF.dgraCx > div > aside > div:nth-child(${i}) > div.sc-dlfnbm.ujoHC > div.sc-hKgILt.beOqPu > div > h2`;
        return [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)]
           .map(elem => elem.innerText);
    },
    i
);
```

Also consider if `.innerText` is really what you need - [it usually isn't](http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/). Use `.textContent` instead if you can.